# Jetpack compose: How to detect what is causing a Composable to recompose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm starting to notice some jank in my app and I believe the cause is composables being re-composed when they should not.

I've detected a few user interactions that trigger unnecessary recompositions but I can't put my finger into what is causing the re-composition. I've added breakpoints in every place where I modify the state and still can find what is triggering the recomposition.

Does AS provide a way to debug this kind of thing?

Comment: I'm afraid not yet

Comment: Thanks MARSK, fortunately, I've detected and fixed the problem. It'd be nice to have some kind of debug mode that 1st shows you what views are being recomposed and 2nd tells you why. I'm sure something like that will be introduced eventually

Comment: Hope for the best

Comment: For anyone coming here like me with a similar question, [this](https://chris.banes.dev/composable-metrics/) is a really good explanation and help to see what gets recomposed and why

Answer (score 6):

## 2023 Answer

Now you can to define recomposition trigger by the normal debugging process.

For this you need to use latest version of `Android Studio Hedgehog`

Here is the a bit more [information](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-hedgehog-release-notes#compose-state-in-debugger) about this new feature

With it you can just put the breakpoints in your `@Composable` function and get the list of changed and unchanged parameters

Comment: Information link has expired. New link is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/past-releases/as-hedgehog-release-notes#compose-state-in-debugger)

Comment: Updated the link in the response, thanks @target33!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no IDE support yet. But you can the use below custom modifier to track the recomposition.

**Demo**

- https://twitter.com/theapache64/status/1502932832058249220

**RecompositionHighlighter.kt**

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.Stable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.composed
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.drawWithCache
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SolidColor
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Fill
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.drawscope.Stroke
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.lerp
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.debugInspectorInfo
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.util.lerp
import kotlin.math.min
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay

/**
 * A [Modifier] that draws a border around elements that are recomposing. The border increases in
 * size and interpolates from red to green as more recompositions occur before a timeout.
 */
@Stable
fun Modifier.recomposeHighlighter(): Modifier = this.then(recomposeModifier)

// Use a single instance + @Stable to ensure that recompositions can enable skipping optimizations
// Modifier.composed will still remember unique data per call site.
private val recomposeModifier =
    Modifier.composed(inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo { name = "recomposeHighlighter" }) {
        // The total number of compositions that have occurred. We're not using a State<> here be
        // able to read/write the value without invalidating (which would cause infinite
        // recomposition).
        val totalCompositions = remember { arrayOf(0L) }
        totalCompositions[0]++

        // The value of totalCompositions at the last timeout.
        val totalCompositionsAtLastTimeout = remember { mutableStateOf(0L) }

        // Start the timeout, and reset everytime there's a recomposition. (Using totalCompositions
        // as the key is really just to cause the timer to restart every composition).
        LaunchedEffect(totalCompositions[0]) {
            delay(3000)
            totalCompositionsAtLastTimeout.value = totalCompositions[0]
        }

        Modifier.drawWithCache {
            onDrawWithContent {
                // Draw actual content.
                drawContent()

                // Below is to draw the highlight, if necessary. A lot of the logic is copied from
                // Modifier.border
                val numCompositionsSinceTimeout =
                    totalCompositions[0] - totalCompositionsAtLastTimeout.value

                val hasValidBorderParams = size.minDimension > 0f
                if (!hasValidBorderParams || numCompositionsSinceTimeout <= 0) {
                    return@onDrawWithContent
                }

                val (color, strokeWidthPx) =
                    when (numCompositionsSinceTimeout) {
                        // We need at least one composition to draw, so draw the smallest border 
                        // color in blue.
                        1L -> Color.Blue to 1f
                        // 2 compositions is _probably_ okay.
                        2L -> Color.Green to 2.dp.toPx()
                        // 3 or more compositions before timeout may indicate an issue. lerp the
                        // color from yellow to red, and continually increase the border size.
                        else -> {
                            lerp(
                                Color.Yellow.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
                                Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                                min(1f, (numCompositionsSinceTimeout - 1).toFloat() / 100f)
                            ) to numCompositionsSinceTimeout.toInt().dp.toPx()
                        }
                    }

                val halfStroke = strokeWidthPx / 2
                val topLeft = Offset(halfStroke, halfStroke)
                val borderSize = Size(size.width - strokeWidthPx, size.height - strokeWidthPx)

                val fillArea = (strokeWidthPx * 2) > size.minDimension
                val rectTopLeft = if (fillArea) Offset.Zero else topLeft
                val size = if (fillArea) size else borderSize
                val style = if (fillArea) Fill else Stroke(strokeWidthPx)

                drawRect(
                    brush = SolidColor(color),
                    topLeft = rectTopLeft,
                    size = size,
                    style = style
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/03/play-time-with-jetpack-compose.html

Comment: how to use this modifier in Prod and Debug builds? and do we need to copy this modifer for each element or  just the root element

Answer (score 1):

For debugging recompose you need Android Studio Electric Eel and after it with recomposition counter.

Example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                    Column {
                        A()
                        B()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun A() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    // Causes recomposition on click
    Button(onClick = { count++ }, Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
        Text("Recompose")
    }

    Text("$count")
    count++ // Backwards write, writing to state after it has been read
}

@Composable
fun B() {
    Text("B")
}
```

in the Column we have A() and B() Compose function.
when a user presses the button in A() we have a [Backward issue](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/bestpractices#avoid-backwards) and recompose infinitely.
for finding the issue we use [Layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/layoutinspector).
You can see the screen recording for debugging below.

[image]
https://www.veed.io/view/2fda4463-a23d-4567-b853-e7f766e9342a?panel=share

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to 'catch' the recomposition trigger, but basically the recomposition is triggered by an observed state that modifier.
In other words, having a `mutableState` or `mutableStateList` that changes triggers the recomposition.
If you want to control this, you can take a look at `Side-Effects`
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects

And particularly this: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#snapshotFlow

Answer (score 0):

In New Android Studio Hedgehog you can directly check what is causing a composable to recompose with the help of Layout Inspector.

1. On bottom right corner u can find layout inspector option
2. Layout Inspector -> View option component tree -> Show Recomposition count
3. By enabling this u can easily see recomposition count
   [image]